# React router dom with layout is not working in build mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

In react app I am using `react-router-dom` for routing.

My layout file is,

```
import { Col, Row } from "antd";
import Sidebar from "../Sidebar";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const AuthLayout = () => {
  return (
    <Row style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }} className="grey-bg">
      <Col span={5}>
        <Sidebar />
      </Col>
      <Col span={18} offset={1}>
        <Outlet />
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
};

export default AuthLayout;
```

Routing file is,

```
const Routing = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isLoggedIn);

  const renderIfLoggedIn = (component) => {
    return isLoggedIn ? component : <Navigate to="/login" replace={true} />;
  };

  const renderIfNotLoggedIn = (component) => {
    return !isLoggedIn ? (
      component
    ) : (
      <Navigate to="/dashboard" replace={true} />
    );
  };

  const handleLoginStateChange = () => {
    dispatch(setLoggedIn());
  };

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<AuthLayout />}>
          <Route path="/" element={renderIfLoggedIn(<Dashboard />)} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={renderIfLoggedIn(<Dashboard />)} />
          <Route path="/register" element={renderIfLoggedIn(<Register />)} />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/login" element={renderIfNotLoggedIn(<Login />)} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default Routing;
```

Now the issue is, in development mode all routes are working fine but in build mode all links are not loading. Through URL directly we can access but through the menu bar.